# PHP regex needed

Tags: php, regex

So far this captures everything i need ending with 'em' i need regex to capture paragraphs ending in 'ppp' also.

My regex:

```
%<h2>Storyline</h2>(.*)em%s
```

Comment: What? Could you give an example of what you want captured, and what you don't want captured?

Comment: Anything that starts with <h2>Storyline</h2> and ends with em OR ppp (stops capturing at the first occurrence of em OR ppp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise not to parse HTML with regex, but this seems easy enough seeing as you aren't actually parsing it as HTML...

```
%<h2>Storyline</h2>(.*?)(?:em|ppp)%s
```

Comment: Why shouldn't HTML be parsed with regex?

Comment: If your HTML consists of a very simple format or one-liner then there is nothing wrong with using regex. However if the structure is unpredictable or large, you're much better off using a parser, like `DOMDocument`, which will handle all the parsing of the markup for you so you can focus on getting the information from the markup.

Comment: @aLk see [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)